# How can I concatenate multiple CSV files using Pandas in Python and handle 'ValueError: No objects to concatenate' error?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import

I'm trying to import multiple csv files but facing some problems, I tried the below code but I get "ValueError: No objects to concatenate" the files have the same column order and values

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

file_names = glob.glob('P:\Operators\Matt\Python/ML_2305,DA_2305.csv')

dfs = []

for file in file_names:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    dfs.append(df)

combined_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

print(combined_df)
```

Comment: in pandas `append` is less effecient than using `concat`. I strongly suggest you to use `concat` which is stack on dataframe on the other. You can stack vertically or horizontally. For more detail please see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask your csv file has the same structure.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

for file in ['csv_1.csv', 'csv_2.csv']:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    dfs.append(df)

combined_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

This works for me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
combined_df = pd.DataFrame() #create an empty dataframe

for file in filename:
    tem = pd.read_csv(f'{file}')
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, tem])
```